# What is the average wait time for a game center real-time match?

Tags: time, real-time, wait, game-center, matchmaking

I haven't found any sources detailing the average wait - time for a game center match maker to find a match. It would also be good to know what an average waiting time that is accepted by users for a 2 player multiplayer mobile game. If possible, please link some references to your answers thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It varies depending on the game, you are going to need to test it out yourself if you want to know.

Comment: On my game, I found an average of 5 - 10 seconds for playing within the same wifi when game center responds. On 4g it was 15 - 30 seconds. It seems a bit long compared to other mobile games I have tested. Perhaps, it is because they host their own server. I am not sure if the game center wait time is normal/acceptable for the players?